# sed find occurances of pattern in a file

Tags: sed, pattern-matching

I have a csv file with tags in the form of ...,fxx=sth,... and would like to check what field values every field can take. Currently I use:

```
cat data.csv | grep "f10=" | sed 's/.*\(f10=[^,]*\).*/\1/g' | sort | uniq
```

However, that only gives me the last match on every line, e.g. if a line has `...,f10=a,...,f10=b,...` then I will always only get the second match.

Is there a better way?

Comment: could you post a small sample/snippet of the csv?

Comment: Probably it's happening cause ... othet `Fxx=sth` are getting replaced with the last `f10=` match. So, best would be separate the line by `,` and then getting the f10= part only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly it's a `,` separated csv, so what you might need is:

```
tr "," "\n" FILE | sed -n '/^f[0-9]\+=/p' | sort | uniq -c
```

`tr` translates the separator to new lines, the `sed` filters out lines without `fXX=` parts, then it gets sorted, distincted.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

If the line ends with a comma,

```
sed -e 's/,f10=/,X=/g' -e 's/f[0-9]*=[^,]*,*//g' -e 's/X=/f10=/' data.csv
```

(If it *doesn't* end with a comma, well, just tack `-e 's/,$//'` on the end.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to use perl instead of sed:

```
grep f10= data.csv | perl -e 'for(<>){ @f=/f10=[^,]+/g; print "@f\n" }' |
sort | uniq
```

Here's what the perl script does:

- `for(<>)` loops through the lines obtained from STDIN
- `@f=/f10=[^,]+/g` matches your regex, `/f10=[^,]+/`, and stores all the occurrences in the `@f` array
- `print "@f\n"` prints the contents of the `@f` array as strings separated by spaces and a newline